# Google Assistant Internal API Endpoint

Tags: google-api, broadcast, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I am currently working on tool that will send an automated message broadcast to all Google Homes in my home. I want to run this tool on a VPS, but unfortunately the Google Assistant SDK only supports broadcasting to Google Homes on the same Wi-Fi network.

However, the Google Assistant app on my phone has no problem broadcasting a message to all my Google Homes, even when I am miles away from my house. So, I am attempting to recreate this effect so that my VPS can broadcast messages to my Google Homes.

I know the Google Assistant SDK endpoint is `embeddedassistant.googleapis.com`, but I do not know the endpoint that is used by the actual app. I tried decompiling the app to find it, but to no avail.

I assume the actual phone app uses a separate endpoint (and internal API) than the app, but I am still trying to find out what it is.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, it appears the Google App's internal API endpoint is:

[https://www.google.com/m/voice-search/up?pair=[Request_ID]](https://www.google.com/m/voice-search/up?pair=%5BRequest_ID%5D)

However, the endpoint does not appear to use protocol buffers and uses a content type called `application/vnd.google.octet-stream-compressible`

The only information I could find is available here (with Google Translate): https://yangwenbo.com/articles/google-app-api-protocol-voice-search.html